# How to find the real manufacturer of my device?

Tags: hardware

Often when we buy phones in contract or otherwise, the vendor company puts its own logo and branding on hardware as well as firmware.

Is there a method to help determine the real identity of a device to root it and perform other functions?

Comment: Do you have a specific OEM in mind? Or a general question?

Comment: You can try [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z&hl=en), it gathers info about your device , manufacturer, hardware etc

Comment: @beeshyams general question

Comment: That's *very broad* , besides your concern is on rooting - which method to use is dependent on device , variants of device, and OS version or one click apps . Not dependent on *who* manufactured it

Comment: CPU-Z, AIDA64 are just one of those. If I understood what you want

Answer (score 3):

One tool that came to mind, is [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z&hl=en).

> Description
>
> Android version of the popular CPU identification tool for PC, CPU-Z
>   is a free application that reports information about your device.
>
> - SoC (System On Chip) name, architecture, clock speed for each core ;
> - System information : **device brand & model**, screen resolution, RAM, storage.;
> - Battery information : level, status, temperature, capacity ;
> - Sensors.

Permissions :

- INTERNET permission is required for the online validation
- ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE for statistics.

[image]